# \listoftables (and figures) STILL won't work (I have tried all I could read about this)

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

I have been using latex for a few months but still very new to some things, I have read EVERY PLACE and post regarding this issue and tried a lot but still no answer. I used the `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` for my thesis but when i went from Overleaf to TexStudio they stopped working. No matter how many different formats of table I tried, I'm beaten. Here is the MWE. In many chapters I need tables and I still get this "??" when I try referencing the table and nothing in the list of tables and the same for figures. Any help would be salvation. Here I provide one of the tables in the preamble but in my original draft its in the C2.tex file. THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR ANY KIND OF HELP.

```
\documentclass[paper=6in:9in,BCOR=9.5mm,DIV=14,10pt,pagesize=pdftex,headings=twolinechapter,chapterprefix=true,american,openright,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}

\usepackage{pxfonts}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[a4paper,headheight=25pt,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, longtable, ragged2e, pdflscape}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\title{bla}
\author{Me}
\date{today}
\begin{document}
    \input{Título}
    
    \input{Abstracto}
    
    \chapter*{Dedicatoria}
    To Mum and Dad 
    
    
    \chapter*{Agradecimientos}
    me myself I and the latex people
    
    
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    
    
    
    \chapter{Introducción general.}
    \input{Introducción.tex}
    \newpage
    \input{Objetivos.tex}
    \chapter{2}
    \input{C2.tex}
    \chapter{3}
    \input{C3.tex}
    \chapter{4}
    \input{C5.tex}
    \chapter{6}
    \input{C6.tex}
    \chapter{7}
    \input{C7.tex}
    \chapter{3.}
    \input{3.tex}
    \chapter{Conclusion}
    \input{conc.tex}
    
    \appendix
    \chapter{5.tex}
    \input{prueba}
    \chapter{6.tex}
    \input{figsup}
    \chapter{7}
    \input{Presypub}
    
    
    \printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

%In chapter 2:%

```
\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\noindent

El perfil de polifenoles de las semillas estudiadas se encuentra en la \ref{tab:2} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{P{1cm} P{3.5cm} P{2cm} P{1cm} P{2cm} P{2cm} P{1cm} P{1.5cm} P{4cm} P{1cm}}
    \caption{Identificación tentativa de polifenoles en chía, lino y sésamo.} \label{tab:2}\\
    \centering
    % header information
    \toprule
    \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre} & \textbf{\thead{Fórmula \\ molecular}} & \textbf{\thead{tR\\(min)}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]-\\Cal.}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]-\\Exp.}} & \textbf{\thead{Error \\ (ppm)}} & \textbf{MS/MS} & \textbf{Grupo} & \textbf{Semilla}\\
    \midrule
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{Tabla 2.1, continúa}\\
    \addlinespace
    \toprule
    \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre} & \textbf{\thead{Fórmula \\ Molecular}} & \textbf{\thead{tR\\(min)}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]$^-$\\Cal.}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]$^-$\\Exp.}} & \textbf{\thead{Error \\ (ppm)}} & \textbf{MS/MS} & \textbf{Grupo} & \textbf{Semilla}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead
    
    % footer information
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{r@{}}{Continúa en la página siguiente}\\
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    % body of longtable
    1 & Ácido quínico & \ce{C7H12O6} & 7,8 & 191,0561 & 191,0572 & -5,9 & - & Ácido orgánico & C, L \\
    \addlinespace
    2 & Ácido cafeico hexósido I & \ce{C15H18O19} & 11,4 & 341,0858 & 341,0878 & 5.9 & 179,0261 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
    \addlinespace
    3 & Danshensu & \ce{C9H10O5} & 11,8 & 197,0455 & 197,0450 & 2.6 & 179,0374 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    4 & Ácido ferúlico hexósido & \ce{C16H20O9} & 11,9 & 355,1021 & 355,1035 & -3,7 & 193,0434 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
    \addlinespace
    5 & Kaempferol dihexósido & \ce{C27H30O16} & 12,1 & 609,1479 & 609,1471 & 2,9 & \thead{447,0763 \\ 285,0300} & Flavonol & L \\
    \addlinespace
    6 & Ácido caftárico & \ce{C13H12O9} & 12,2 & 311,0409 & 311,0428 & 6,2 & 179,0353 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    7 & Triptófano & \ce{C11H12N2O2} & 12,5 & 203,0826 & 203,0816 & -4,7 & 186,0626 & Aminoácido & C, L, S \\
    \addlinespace
    8 & Nortraquelósido I & \ce{C26H32O12} & 12,9 & 535,1766 & 535,1821 & 10,2 & \thead{373,1197 \\ 327,0736} & Lignano & L, S \\
    \addlinespace
    9 & Eriodictiol hexósido & \ce{C21H22O11} & 12,9 & 449,1091 & 449,1089 & -1,6 & \thead{287,0439 \\ 269,0345 \\ 259,0495} & Flavanona & L \\
    \addlinespace
    10 & Ácido cafeico hexósido II & \ce{C15H18O9} & 13,0 & 341,0878 & 341,0872 & -1,9 & 179,0336 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    11 & Ácido salvianólico I/H & \ce{C27H22O12} & 13,0 & 537,1038 & 537,1090 & -1,7 & \thead{339,0489 \\ 295,0616} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    12 & Nortraquelogenina & \ce{C20H22O7} & 13,0 & 373,1281 & 373,1293 & -11,7 & \thead{355,1002 \\ 327,1115} & Lignano & L, S \\
    \addlinespace
    13 & Ácido fertárico & \ce{C14H14O9} & 13,3 & 323,0565 & 325,0568 & -1.0 & 193,0503 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    14 & Quercetina dihexósido & \ce{C27H30O17} & 13,4 & 625,1443 & 625,1410 & 5,2 & 463,0731 & Flavonol & L \\
    \addlinespace
    15 & Lariciresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H34O16} & 13,6 & 683,2579 & 683,2557 & 3,2 & \thead{521,1302 \\ 359,1401 \\ 329,1385} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    16 & Secoisolariciresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H46O16} & 14,2 & 685,2775 & 685,2713 & 9,1 & \thead{523,1981 \\ 361,1485} & Lignano & L \\
    \addlinespace
    17 & Ácido salvianólico E/B/L & \ce{C36H30O16} & 14,2 & 717,1461 & 717,1494 & -4,6 & \thead{537,1038 \\ 519,0961 \\ 475,1036 \\ 339,0478} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    18 & Matairesinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H42O16} & 14,2 & 681,2391 & 681,2400 & 1,4 & \thead{357,1382 \\ 323,0968 \\ 221,0643} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    19 & Ácido cafeico & \ce{C9H8O4} & 14,6 & 179,0340 & 179,0350 & -5,3 & - &  Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    20 & Lariciresinol hexósido & \ce{C26H34O11} & 14,9 & 521,1988 & 521,2028 & 7,8 & \thead{359,1626 \\ 329,1487} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    21 & Pinoresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H42O16} & 15,4 & 681,2364 & 681,2400 & -5,3 & \thead{357,1339 \\ 323,0920 \\ 151,4950} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    22 & Ácido ferúlico & \ce{C10H10O4} & 15,5 & 193,0527 & 193,0506 & -11,0 & - & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
    \addlinespace
    23 & Nortraquelósido II & \ce{C26H32O12} & 15,9 & 535,1766 & 535,1821 & 10,2 & \thead{373,1327 \\ 329,1258} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    24 & Mata/Pino (acetil)-dihexósido$^a$ & \ce{C34H44O17} & 16,3 & 723,2519 & 723,2506 & 1,8 & \thead{519,1854 \\ 357,1332} & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    25 & Mata/Pino hexósido I$^a$ & \ce{C26H32O11} & 16,4 & 519,1854 & 519,1872 & -3,5 & 357,1319 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    26 & Salviaflásido I & \ce{C24H26O13} & 17,3 & 521,1301 & 521,1378 & -14,9 & \thead{359,0769 \\ 197,0499} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    27 & Mata/Pino hexósido II$^a$ & \ce{C26H32O11} & 17,8 & 519,1813 & 519,1872 & -11,4 & 357,1317 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    28 & Salviaflásido II & \ce{C24H26O13} & 18,2 & 521,1301 & 521,1336 & -6,8 & \thead{359,0812 \\ 197,0467} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    29 & Mata/Pino (acetil)-hexósido$^a$ & \ce{C34H43O17} & 18,6 & 561,1983 & 561,1978 & 0,9 & 357,1305 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    30 & Ácido rosmarínico I & \ce{C18H16O8} & 19,1 & 359,0772 & 359,0776 & 1,1 & \thead{197,0450 \\ 179,0345 \\ 161,0237} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    31 & Sesaminol trihexósido & \ce{C38H48O22} & 19,5 & 855,2728 & 855,2564 & -19,1 & - & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    32 & Ácido rosmarínico II & \ce{C18H16O8} & 19,6 & 359,0772 & 359,0774 & -0,6 & \thead{197,0473 \\ 179,0358 \\ 161,0256} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    33 & Narirutina hexósido & \ce{C33H42O19} & 19,8 & 741,2248 & 741,1491 & 23,2 & 579,1263 & Flavanona & C \\
    \addlinespace
    34 & Kaeósido & \ce{C21H20O11} & 20,2 & 447,03 & 447,0918 & -3,3 &  \thead{255,0192 \\ 227,0257} & Flavonol & L \\
    \addlinespace
    35 & Isoramo & \ce{C21H18O13} & 20,6 & 477,17 & 477,18 & -6,5 & \thead{315,0280 \\ 300,0111} & Flavonol & L \\
    \addlinespace
    36 & Áci C & \ce{C26H20O10} & 21,6 & 84 & 4000 & -3,3 & \thead{31,0565 \\ 293,0390} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    37 & Sesaminol dihexósido I & \ce{C32H38O17} & 22,4 & 693,2060 & 693,2036 & -3.4 & - & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    38 & Metil rosmarinato & \ce{C19H18O8} & 22,5 & 373,0929 & 373,0917 & -3,3 & 179,0373 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
    \addlinespace
    39 & Sesamolinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H40O17} & 22,9 & 695,2279 & 695,2193 & -12,4 & - & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    40 & Sesaminol dihexósido II & \ce{C32H38O17} & 23,3 & 693,1955 & 693,2036 & 11,7 & 369,0918 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    41 & Sesaminol dihexósido III & \ce{C32H38O17} & 23,9 & 693,1963 & 693,2036 & -10 & - & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    42 & Sesamolinol acetil-hexósido & \ce{C28H32O13} & 25,6 & 575,1775 & 575,1770 & -0,8 & 371,1126 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    43 & Seo & \ce{C26H28O12} & 26,1 & 531,1498 & 531,1508 & -2,0 & 369,0941 & Lignano & S \\
    \addlinespace
    44 & Sesamido & \ce{C28H30O13} & 27,3 & 573,1596 & 573,1614 & -3,0 & 369,0968 & Lignano & S \\
\end{longtable}
\footnotesize{$^a$ ``Mata'' y ``Pino'' son las formas acortadas de Mataresinol y Pinoresinol, respectivamente.}\\
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: You should start here: Remove *everything* within `\begin{document}`...`\end{document}` and then just add your first document element. Does the document compile? If so, move on and add another component, compile and check the output.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To ask the "obvious" question -- did you process the file twice?  Information for the TOC and "lists of" are saved up in the first pass (written out to one or more `.aux` files, and read in and set on the later pass.  If you delete the `.aux` files before a second pass, that will leave the processing with nothing to show for these lists.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you all for your kind answers and welcome messages.  I have compiled with both the compile and build and view button (separately) and 2 consecutive times and in different orders and combinations too. (In some opportunities 3 or 4 times just in case) and still no answer. @barbarabeeton

Comment: Delete/comment line `\centering` in the third line of your `longtable`.

Comment: @Mensch Hi!!, I have just tried it, and then I compiled twice again and no answer yet :/

Comment: you should get all ?? resolved when you run latex the second time, but if you want help with a problem then you should post an example that generates the problem. No one can run the code you have posted as it includes files we don't have. Start with a copy of the document and just include the smallest part that shows the problem, probably a singl `\listoftables` and a single `table` and no `\input`. Check the problem still occurs with the test document and edit your question so the example has the test document

Comment: Check after the first compilation if a file with the ending lot exists and what content it has.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your code are several errors/missunderstandings, for example I corrected the order of some package calls to get rid of some error messages/warnings. I also used class `scrreprt` instead `report` because you used options only available in KOMA-Script classes (for example `scrreprt`).

I created an compilable TeX code from your given code and corrected/commented out line `\centering` in the given table.

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,BCOR=9.5mm,DIV=14,10pt,pagesize=pdftex,
    headings=twolinechapter,chapterprefix=true,american,openright,twoside
]{scrreprt}
    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper,headheight=25pt,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}



\usepackage{textcomp}
    
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{futs}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    
    \usepackage{anysize}

    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{gensymb}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \usepackage{svg}
    
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{chemformula}
    \usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{tablefootnote}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
    \newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=small}\caption*{#1}}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear,uniquename=init,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
    
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{nicematrix}
    \usepackage{booktabs, array, longtable, ragged2e, pdflscape}
    
    
\usepackage{hyperref}

    \title{bla}
    \author{Me}
    \date{today}
    \begin{document}
%       \input{Título}
        
%       \input{Abstracto}
        
        \chapter*{Dedicatoria}
        To Mum and Dad 
        
        
        \chapter*{Agradecimientos}
        me myself I and the latex people
        
        
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        
        
        
        \chapter{Introducción general.}
 %      \input{Introducción.tex}
        \newpage
%       \input{Objetivos.tex}
        \chapter{2}
%       \input{C2.tex}
        %In chapter 2:%
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{3em}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
    \noindent
    
    El perfil de polifenoles de las semillas estudiadas se encuentra en la \ref{tab:2} 
    
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    
    
    \begin{landscape}
        
        \begin{longtable}{P{1cm} P{3.5cm} P{2cm} P{1cm} P{2cm} P{2cm} P{1cm} P{1.5cm} P{4cm} P{1cm}}
            \caption{Identificación tentativa de polifenoles en chía, lino y sésamo.} \label{tab:2}\\
%           \centering % <====================================================
            % header information
            \toprule
            \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre} & \textbf{\thead{Fórmula \\ molecular}} & \textbf{\thead{tR\\(min)}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]-\\Cal.}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]-\\Exp.}} & \textbf{\thead{Error \\ (ppm)}} & \textbf{MS/MS} & \textbf{Grupo} & \textbf{Semilla}\\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead
            
            \multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{Tabla 2.1, continúa}\\
            \addlinespace
            \toprule
            \textbf{Nº} & \textbf{Nombre} & \textbf{\thead{Fórmula \\ Molecular}} & \textbf{\thead{tR\\(min)}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]$^-$\\Cal.}} & \textbf{\thead{[M-H]$^-$\\Exp.}} & \textbf{\thead{Error \\ (ppm)}} & \textbf{MS/MS} & \textbf{Grupo} & \textbf{Semilla}\\
            \midrule
            \endhead
            
            % footer information
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{10}{r@{}}{Continúa en la página siguiente}\\
            \endfoot
            
            \bottomrule
            \endlastfoot
            
            % body of longtable
            1 & Ácido quínico & \ce{C7H12O6} & 7,8 & 191,0561 & 191,0572 & -5,9 & - & Ácido orgánico & C, L \\
            \addlinespace
            2 & Ácido cafeico hexósido I & \ce{C15H18O19} & 11,4 & 341,0858 & 341,0878 & 5.9 & 179,0261 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
            \addlinespace
            3 & Danshensu & \ce{C9H10O5} & 11,8 & 197,0455 & 197,0450 & 2.6 & 179,0374 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            4 & Ácido ferúlico hexósido & \ce{C16H20O9} & 11,9 & 355,1021 & 355,1035 & -3,7 & 193,0434 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
            \addlinespace
            5 & Kaempferol dihexósido & \ce{C27H30O16} & 12,1 & 609,1479 & 609,1471 & 2,9 & \thead{447,0763 \\ 285,0300} & Flavonol & L \\
            \addlinespace
            6 & Ácido caftárico & \ce{C13H12O9} & 12,2 & 311,0409 & 311,0428 & 6,2 & 179,0353 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            7 & Triptófano & \ce{C11H12N2O2} & 12,5 & 203,0826 & 203,0816 & -4,7 & 186,0626 & Aminoácido & C, L, S \\
            \addlinespace
            8 & Nortraquelósido I & \ce{C26H32O12} & 12,9 & 535,1766 & 535,1821 & 10,2 & \thead{373,1197 \\ 327,0736} & Lignano & L, S \\
            \addlinespace
            9 & Eriodictiol hexósido & \ce{C21H22O11} & 12,9 & 449,1091 & 449,1089 & -1,6 & \thead{287,0439 \\ 269,0345 \\ 259,0495} & Flavanona & L \\
            \addlinespace
            10 & Ácido cafeico hexósido II & \ce{C15H18O9} & 13,0 & 341,0878 & 341,0872 & -1,9 & 179,0336 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            11 & Ácido salvianólico I/H & \ce{C27H22O12} & 13,0 & 537,1038 & 537,1090 & -1,7 & \thead{339,0489 \\ 295,0616} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            12 & Nortraquelogenina & \ce{C20H22O7} & 13,0 & 373,1281 & 373,1293 & -11,7 & \thead{355,1002 \\ 327,1115} & Lignano & L, S \\
            \addlinespace
            13 & Ácido fertárico & \ce{C14H14O9} & 13,3 & 323,0565 & 325,0568 & -1.0 & 193,0503 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            14 & Quercetina dihexósido & \ce{C27H30O17} & 13,4 & 625,1443 & 625,1410 & 5,2 & 463,0731 & Flavonol & L \\
            \addlinespace
            15 & Lariciresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H34O16} & 13,6 & 683,2579 & 683,2557 & 3,2 & \thead{521,1302 \\ 359,1401 \\ 329,1385} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            16 & Secoisolariciresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H46O16} & 14,2 & 685,2775 & 685,2713 & 9,1 & \thead{523,1981 \\ 361,1485} & Lignano & L \\
            \addlinespace
            17 & Ácido salvianólico E/B/L & \ce{C36H30O16} & 14,2 & 717,1461 & 717,1494 & -4,6 & \thead{537,1038 \\ 519,0961 \\ 475,1036 \\ 339,0478} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            18 & Matairesinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H42O16} & 14,2 & 681,2391 & 681,2400 & 1,4 & \thead{357,1382 \\ 323,0968 \\ 221,0643} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            19 & Ácido cafeico & \ce{C9H8O4} & 14,6 & 179,0340 & 179,0350 & -5,3 & - &  Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            20 & Lariciresinol hexósido & \ce{C26H34O11} & 14,9 & 521,1988 & 521,2028 & 7,8 & \thead{359,1626 \\ 329,1487} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            21 & Pinoresinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H42O16} & 15,4 & 681,2364 & 681,2400 & -5,3 & \thead{357,1339 \\ 323,0920 \\ 151,4950} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            22 & Ácido ferúlico & \ce{C10H10O4} & 15,5 & 193,0527 & 193,0506 & -11,0 & - & Ácido hidroxicinámico & L \\
            \addlinespace
            23 & Nortraquelósido II & \ce{C26H32O12} & 15,9 & 535,1766 & 535,1821 & 10,2 & \thead{373,1327 \\ 329,1258} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            24 & Mata/Pino (acetil)-dihexósido$^a$ & \ce{C34H44O17} & 16,3 & 723,2519 & 723,2506 & 1,8 & \thead{519,1854 \\ 357,1332} & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            25 & Mata/Pino hexósido I$^a$ & \ce{C26H32O11} & 16,4 & 519,1854 & 519,1872 & -3,5 & 357,1319 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            26 & Salviaflásido I & \ce{C24H26O13} & 17,3 & 521,1301 & 521,1378 & -14,9 & \thead{359,0769 \\ 197,0499} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            27 & Mata/Pino hexósido II$^a$ & \ce{C26H32O11} & 17,8 & 519,1813 & 519,1872 & -11,4 & 357,1317 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            28 & Salviaflásido II & \ce{C24H26O13} & 18,2 & 521,1301 & 521,1336 & -6,8 & \thead{359,0812 \\ 197,0467} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            29 & Mata/Pino (acetil)-hexósido$^a$ & \ce{C34H43O17} & 18,6 & 561,1983 & 561,1978 & 0,9 & 357,1305 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            30 & Ácido rosmarínico I & \ce{C18H16O8} & 19,1 & 359,0772 & 359,0776 & 1,1 & \thead{197,0450 \\ 179,0345 \\ 161,0237} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            31 & Sesaminol trihexósido & \ce{C38H48O22} & 19,5 & 855,2728 & 855,2564 & -19,1 & - & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            32 & Ácido rosmarínico II & \ce{C18H16O8} & 19,6 & 359,0772 & 359,0774 & -0,6 & \thead{197,0473 \\ 179,0358 \\ 161,0256} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            33 & Narirutina hexósido & \ce{C33H42O19} & 19,8 & 741,2248 & 741,1491 & 23,2 & 579,1263 & Flavanona & C \\
            \addlinespace
            34 & Kaeósido & \ce{C21H20O11} & 20,2 & 447,03 & 447,0918 & -3,3 &  \thead{255,0192 \\ 227,0257} & Flavonol & L \\
            \addlinespace
            35 & Isoramo & \ce{C21H18O13} & 20,6 & 477,17 & 477,18 & -6,5 & \thead{315,0280 \\ 300,0111} & Flavonol & L \\
            \addlinespace
            36 & Áci C & \ce{C26H20O10} & 21,6 & 84 & 4000 & -3,3 & \thead{31,0565 \\ 293,0390} & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            37 & Sesaminol dihexósido I & \ce{C32H38O17} & 22,4 & 693,2060 & 693,2036 & -3.4 & - & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            38 & Metil rosmarinato & \ce{C19H18O8} & 22,5 & 373,0929 & 373,0917 & -3,3 & 179,0373 & Ácido hidroxicinámico & C \\
            \addlinespace
            39 & Sesamolinol dihexósido & \ce{C32H40O17} & 22,9 & 695,2279 & 695,2193 & -12,4 & - & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            40 & Sesaminol dihexósido II & \ce{C32H38O17} & 23,3 & 693,1955 & 693,2036 & 11,7 & 369,0918 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            41 & Sesaminol dihexósido III & \ce{C32H38O17} & 23,9 & 693,1963 & 693,2036 & -10 & - & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            42 & Sesamolinol acetil-hexósido & \ce{C28H32O13} & 25,6 & 575,1775 & 575,1770 & -0,8 & 371,1126 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            43 & Seo & \ce{C26H28O12} & 26,1 & 531,1498 & 531,1508 & -2,0 & 369,0941 & Lignano & S \\
            \addlinespace
            44 & Sesamido & \ce{C28H30O13} & 27,3 & 573,1596 & 573,1614 & -3,0 & 369,0968 & Lignano & S \\
        \end{longtable}
        \footnotesize{$^a$ ``Mata'' y ``Pino'' son las formas acortadas de Mataresinol y Pinoresinol, respectivamente.}\\
    \end{landscape} 
    
        \chapter{3}
%       \input{C3.tex}
        \chapter{4}
 %      \input{C5.tex}
        \chapter{6}
 %      \input{C6.tex}
        \chapter{7}
 %      \input{C7.tex}
        \chapter{3.}
 %      \input{3.tex}
        \chapter{Conclusion}
 %      \input{conc.tex}
        
        \appendix
        \chapter{5.tex}
 %      \input{prueba}
        \chapter{6.tex}
 %      \input{figsup}
        \chapter{7}
 %      \input{Presypub}
        
        
        \printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

I get the following first page of the table:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your corrected version! It gave the work a more professional look and layout im loving it! i cut the real name of chapter 2 in the MWE to avoid making it too long, the thing now is that with the real name the title doesnt fit in one line.  Regarding the initial question, the list of tables page is still empty and the ?? marks are still there too but I LOVED your corrected version thank you very very much I honestly appreciate it!!

Comment: @Fred21 If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).